# Problemas con authenticate de passport

Tags: nodejs, express, passport

Estoy teniendo problemas con un proyecto CRUD en nodejs, con autenticacion de passport, al momento de hacer el login la pagina se queda cargando y no redirecciona.

```
// Config 
passport.use('local-signin', new localStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, async (email, password, done) => {

    //coincidir con el usuario de correos electrónico
    const user = await User.findOne({email})
    if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'No existe el usuario'});
    } else {
        // coincidir con el usuario de contraseña
        const match = await user.matchPassword(password)
        if(match) {
            return(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Contraseña incorrecta'})
        }
    }
}));
```

Creo que el error se encuentra en la ruta de autenticacion.

```
// Ruta
router.post('/signin', 
    passport.authenticate('local-signin', {
    failureRedirect: '/signin'}),
        function(req, res){
            res.redirect('/notes')
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Al buscar en la colección debes especificar el campo **email**.

Código de ejemplo:

Antes:

```
//coincidir con el usuario de correos electrónico
const user = await User.findOne({email})
```

Después:

```
//coincidir con el usuario de correos electrónico
const user = await User.findOne({email:email})
```

Espero haber ayudado compañero.